# Accesing to DOM elements inside a WebView

Tags: javascript, react-native, canvas

I'm using react-native-signature-canvas which uses a webview which has a canvas. I need that canvas to get a png img. That is working ok.

But lets say I want to access to the canvas object itself to do whatever I want with if from React Native itself. How can I do that?

```
<Signature
    ref={component => this.signatureRef = component}
/>
```

Then, this.signatureRef....

Comment: `this.signatureRef.current` is your `Signature` now.

Comment: Yeah but, that’s the we view, I need the canvas inside the web view

Comment: Unless the library exposes some methods to interact with the canvas in `WebView`, I don't think you can access the canvas object. Your React Native code lives in a JavaScript environment and the things in  `WebView` live in another JavaScript environment.

Comment: Ok, the my best bet is to fork the package to fit my needs. Thanks